# how to add a whitespace in PHP in input box?

Tags: php, html, web

I was trying to print  default value of age in a input box with php

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="age *" value=<?php  echo $_SESSION['age']." "."year";  ?> />
```

like $_SESSION['age'] value is 21 ,
I expecting text in input box like "21 year"
but it gives me "21"

I want one whitespace between 21 and year.
please help me  ....

Comment: Do you have validation/instruction to enforce that 'year' is added when a user inputs there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `value=""` to `value="<?php  echo $_SESSION['age']. " " ."year";  ?>"`

you have not concatenated a space there. Please see `. " " .`

Answer (score 3):

That would be `<?php echo $_SESSION['age']." year"; ?>`, i.e. space directly before "year", within the quotes, and *one*  dot instead of to before `" year"` to concatenate.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Based on your acceptance of the other answer, this would've worked fine too. They both do the same thing.

Comment: since the question was about the space between the number and the word "years", I didn't care about the rest, but certainly you would also need to set the echoed `value` inside quotes to make it work as a valid attribute: `value="<?php echo $_SESSION['age']." year"; ?>"`